# How can I evaluate the bound object in a grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

```
<ItemTemplate>
        <%# ShowDescription((ClassName) Eval("this")) %>
</ItemTemplate>
```

I bind a list of objects to my gridview
and in my gridview want to evaluate (call a function on) the bound object or bound object by row. Not the property of the bound object but the object itself. The above code obviously gives me an error and

```
<ItemTemplate>
        <%# ShowDescription((ClassName) this) %>
</ItemTemplate>
```

means it tries to parse the aspx page

So How can I evaluate the bound object in a grid view or I can't at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the following:

```
<ItemTemplate>
        <%# ShowDescription((ClassName)Container.DataItem) %>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<ItemTemplate>
   <asp:Label ID="lblDesc" runat="server" Text='<%# ShowDescription((ClassName) Eval("this")) %>'></asp:Label>     
</ItemTemplate>
```